# Unmounted Component Expo Error Crashes the App

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native

The given code shows the following error sometimes and crashes the app.
Also, the firebase listener still keeps listening after unsubscribing

Well, I tried a lot of solutions... None of them worked.. Could you please help me with that?

I don't know why.. even after unsbscribing from the listener... this one still fires up on SignUp Screen :

```
unsubscribe = firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {          

            if (user) {

              firebase.firestore().collection("User Details").doc(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid).get().then((snap) => {

                try{

                if(snap.exists){

                  unsubscribe();
                  navigation.reset({
                    index : 0,
                    routes : [{ name : 'Tab'}],
                });

                }else {
                  unsubscribe();
                  navigation.reset({
                    index : 0,
                    routes : [{ name : 'User'}],
                });
                }

                }catch(e){console.log(e)}

              });

                return;


            }

            navigation.reset({
              index : 0,
              routes : [{ name : 'SignUp'}],
            });

          });

        }
      }catch(e){console.log(e)}

    }, [isReady]);
```

> Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component.
> This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application.
> To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect
> cleanup function. at
> node_modules\react-native\Libraries\LogBox\LogBox.js:173:8 in
> registerError at
> node_modules\react-native\Libraries\LogBox\LogBox.js:59:8 in errorImpl
> at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\LogBox\LogBox.js:33:4 in
> console.error at
> node_modules\expo\build\environment\react-native-logs.fx.js:27:4 in
> error at
> node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:106:4
> in printWarning at
> node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:75:16
> in error at
> node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:19152:9
> in warnAboutUpdateOnUnmountedFiberInDEV at
> node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:17093:40
> in scheduleUpdateOnFiber at
> node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:11003:16
> in dispatchAction at
> http://127.0.0.1:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:228649:22
> in getToken$ at node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:63:36 in
> tryCatch at node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:294:29 in
> invoke at node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:63:36 in
> tryCatch at node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:155:27 in
> invoke at node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:165:18 in
> PromiseImpl.resolve.then$argument_0 at
> node_modules\react-native\node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:37:13
> in tryCallOne at
> node_modules\react-native\node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:123:24 in setImmediate$argument_0 at
> node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:130:14 in
> _callTimer at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:181:14 in
> _callImmediatesPass at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:441:30 in
> callImmediates at
> node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:387:6
> in __callImmediates at
> node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:135:6
> in __guard$argument_0 at
> node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:364:10
> in __guard at
> node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:134:4
> in flushedQueue

Here's the code :

Splash screen :

```
try{
  if(!firebase.apps.length){

    firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

  }
}catch(err){
  console.log(err);
}

const cacheResourcesAsync = async () => {

    const images = [
      //Images

    ];
  
    const cacheImages = images.map(image => {
      return Asset.fromModule(image).downloadAsync();
    }); 

    return Promise.all(cacheImages);
}


export const SplashLoadingScreen = () => {

    const [isReady, setIsReady] = useState(false);
    const [isFire, setIsFire] = useState(false);
    const [isFont, setIsFont] = useState(false);
    const [isImages, setIsImages] = useState(false);

    const navigation = useNavigation();

    var unsubscribe;

    //Loading Fonts

    const [michromaLoaded] = useMichroma({ Michroma_400Regular });

    const [latoLoaded] = useLato({ Lato_700Bold });

    //Checking if the fonts are ready
    useEffect(() => {
      if(michromaLoaded && latoLoaded){
        setIsFont(true);
      }
    }, [michromaLoaded, latoLoaded]);

    //Checking if the Images are loaded or not
    useEffect(() => {

      cacheResourcesAsync();
      setIsImages(true);    
      
    }, []);


    //Checking if Firebase is fired up
    useEffect(() => {
      if(firebase.apps.length !== 0){

        setIsFire(true);

      }

    }, [firebase.apps.length]);

    var time;

    //Last Check before moving to other screen
    useEffect(() => {

      if(isFont && isImages && isFire){
        
        time = setTimeout(() => {
          setIsReady(true);
        }, 5000);

      }

      return () => clearTimeout(time);
  
    }, [isFont, isImages, isFire]);   

    //Moving to other screens
    useEffect(() => {

      try{

        if(isReady){

          unsubscribe = firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {          
            
            if (user) {

              firebase.firestore().collection("User Details").doc(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid).get().then((snap) => {
        
                try{

                if(snap.exists){
      
                  unsubscribe();
                  navigation.reset({
                    index : 0,
                    routes : [{ name : 'Tab'}],
                });
                  
                }else {
                  unsubscribe();
                  navigation.reset({
                    index : 0,
                    routes : [{ name : 'User'}],
                });
                }

                }catch(e){console.log(e)}
      
              });
                
                return;
            
              
            }
    
            navigation.reset({
              index : 0,
              routes : [{ name : 'SignUp'}],
            });
    
          });

        }
      }catch(e){console.log(e)}

    }, [isReady]);



    SplashScreen.hideAsync();
```

SignUp Screen :

```
const firebaseConfig = {
  //firebase Config
};

export const SignUpScreen = () => {

  const recaptchaVerifier = useRef(null);
  const verificationCodeTextInput = useRef(null);
  const [phoneNumber, setPhoneNumber] = useState('');
  const [verificationId, setVerificationId] = useState('');
  const [verifyError, setVerifyError] = useState();
  const [verifyInProgress, setVerifyInProgress] = useState(false);
  const [verificationCode, setVerificationCode] = useState('');
  const [confirmError, setConfirmError] = useState();
  const [confirmInProgress, setConfirmInProgress] = useState(false);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const isConfigValid = !!firebaseConfig.apiKey;

  const navigation = useNavigation();

  const registerForPushNotificationsAsync = async () => {

      const { status: existingStatus } = await Notifications.getPermissionsAsync();
      let finalStatus = existingStatus;
      if (existingStatus !== 'granted') {
        const { status } = await Notifications.requestPermissionsAsync();
        finalStatus = status;
      }
      if (finalStatus !== 'granted') {
        alert('Failed to get push token for push notification!');
        return;
      }
  
    if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
      Notifications.setNotificationChannelAsync('high', {
        name: 'high',
        importance: Notifications.AndroidImportance.MAX,
        vibrationPattern: [250, 250, 250, 250],
        lightColor: '#1c1c1c',
        sound : 'royal.wav'
      });
    }
    };

  registerForPushNotificationsAsync();

  const confirmation = async () => {
    const unsubscribe = firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {          
          
      if (user) {

        firebase.firestore().collection("User Details").doc(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid).get().then((snap) => {
  
          try{

          if(snap.exists){

            unsubscribe();
            navigation.reset({
              index : 0,
              routes : [{ name : 'Tab'}],
            });
            
          }else {
            unsubscribe();
            navigation.reset({
              index : 0,
              routes : [{ name : 'User'}],
            });
          }

          }catch(e){console.log(e)}

        });
        
      }
    });
  }
  
  const ConfirmCode = async () => {
    
      setIsLoading(true);
      setConfirmError(undefined);
      setConfirmInProgress(true);
      const credential = firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider.credential(
        verificationId,
        verificationCode
      );

      try{

      await firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(credential).then((user) => {}).catch(e => console.log(e));

      }catch (err) {
        setConfirmError(err);
        setConfirmInProgress(false);
      }

      setConfirmInProgress(false);
      setVerificationId('');
      setVerificationCode('');

      verificationCodeTextInput.current?.clear();

      try{
        await confirmation();
      }catch(e){console.log(e)}

  }
```